# How to specify StringFormat for all TextBlocks bound to float / double value

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

Is there a way to specify StringFormat for all `TextBlocks` bound to a float or double value? So for example cases like this one:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AFloatProperty}" />
```

where `AFloatProperty` is of type float, would have StringFormat set to F3 (or some other format that is to be applied application wide). So that I don't have to specify it for each and every `TextBlock` like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AFloatProperty, StringFormat=F3}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how use case specific your question is, but this should work regarding the exact question.

Add this to `App.xaml`

```
<Application.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
       <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=., StringFormat=F3}" />
   </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then bind your `TextBlock` `DataContext` property instead of its `Text` property.

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Path=AFloatProperty}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to TextBlock you may use a Label

```
<Label Content="{Binding AFloatProperty}"/>
```

with a default Style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="F3"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: As OP is simply formatting floats, this is probably the way to go as he most likely doesn't need the features of a `TextBlock` such as wrapping. However, since `Label` inherits from `ContentControl`, it is the heavier of the two controls. This is moot in most scenarios, but should be noted.